# How to get Diffie-Hellman Group Exhange working on Jaramiko SSH server?

Tags: java, android, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys

I am trying to write a SSH server using Jaramiko, the server should run on an Android platform.

Below is the relevant code, on the line `serverTransport.start(serverInterface, NEGOTIATION_TIME_OUT);` the server fails to perform DH Group Exchange SHA 1 with the client.

This log message was produced:

> 06-26 12:59:57.854 1383-1425/com.jannatec.sshserver D/SSHService:
>   Starting SSH session 06-26 12:59:57.940
>   1383-1426/com.jannatec.sshserver W/System.err: 424 [jaramiko server
>   feeder] INFO net.lag.jaramiko.BaseTransport - Connected (version 2.0,
>   client PuTTY_Release_0.69) 06-26 12:59:58.670
>   1383-1426/com.jannatec.sshserver W/System.err: 1155 [jaramiko server
>   feeder] WARN net.lag.jaramiko.BaseTransport - Oops, unhandled packet
>   type kex4 06-26 12:59:58.678 1383-1426/com.jannatec.sshserver
>   W/System.err: 1163 [jaramiko server feeder] INFO
>   net.lag.jaramiko.BaseTransport - Disconnect (code 2): Server protocol
>   violation: unexpected SSH2_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED packet 06-26 12:59:58.730
>   1383-1425/com.jannatec.sshserver E/SSHService: Negotiation failed

I am using PuTTY as the SSH client, how can I get the key exchange working?

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating transport");
            serverTransport = new ServerTransport(socket);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot create transport");
        }

        final String privateKeyPath = getFilesDir() + "/private.key";
        final String password = "Eh3rLFOtbQoB8jaAQE5i"; 
        File privateKeyFile = new File(privateKeyPath);
        RSAKey rsaKey = null;
        CraiJCE craiJCE = new CraiJCE();
        if (privateKeyFile.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Host key found, loading stored host key");
            try {
                FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(privateKeyPath);
                rsaKey = (RSAKey) PKey.readPrivateKeyFromStream(is, password);
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot load stored key");
            }
        }

        // if there is error loading the key or key does not exist, create a new one
        if (rsaKey == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No stored host key found, generating new key");
            try {
                rsaKey = RSAKey.generate(craiJCE, 1024);

                Log.d(TAG, "Key generated, storing key");
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyPath);
                rsaKey.writePrivateKeyToStream(os, password);
                os.close();
            } catch (SSHException sshe) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Key generation error");
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot store key file");
            }
        }

        serverTransport.addServerKey(rsaKey); 
        if (BANNER.length() > 0) {
            serverTransport.setServerBanner(BANNER + "\n");
        }
        serverTransport.setKeepAlive(60000);
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting SSH session");
            serverTransport.start(serverInterface, NEGOTIATION_TIME_OUT);

        } catch (SSHException sshe) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Negotiation failed");
            cancel();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket IO exception");
            cancel();
        }
    }
```